# How does % work on this C program? (sum of odd and even integers)

Tags: c, sum

here's the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
       int i, N, oddSum = 0, evenSum = 0;


printf("Enter the value of N\n");
    scanf ("%d", &N);
for (i=1; i <=N; i++)
      {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            evenSum = evenSum + i;
        else
            oddSum = oddSum + i;
    }
printf ("Sum of all odd numbers  = %d\n", oddSum);
    printf ("Sum of all even numbers = %d\n", evenSum);

}
```

In this program it gets a number from user (N) and then prints sum of odd and even numbers in two different lines.

two questions:

1- how does % work here?
2- explain this line completely:

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
        evenSum = evenSum + i;
```

Comment: if the `rest` of the `division` is `equal` to `0` the `condition` is `true` otherwise `false`! Is that enough?

Comment: It's using modulo arithmetic to inefficiently test if a number is even. You can do the same thing more efficiently by testing the least significant bit (if set, the number is odd).

Comment: For even more efficiency, forego conditionals and use an index into a two-element-array instead. `int evenodd[2] = {0}; evenodd[i&1] += i;` Naturally, you could just determine the closed arithmetic expression and use that, for an O(1) solution. BTW: The return-type of `main` is `int`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: it's irrelevant, any average optimizing compiler will produce an `andl` instruction for `% 2`

Comment: @Jack: That's only true for unsigned integers. That would be an invalid replacement if `i` is signed. Consider what happens when you do `-1 % 2` vs. `-1 & 1`; one yields **-1** the other gives **1**.

Comment: @Rizier123 I know how if works. consider 4 as i, it would be 4-2 * 4/2 which yields 2, not 0. how does it work then?

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman It is still irrelevant for a good compiler.  Such a compiler does not optimize `i % 2` and then `if (result == 0)`.  A good compiler optimizes `if (i % 2 == 0)` which will provide the same negated code as `if (i & 1)` for both `int i` and `unsigned i`.   I prefer `i & 1` as I often work with less than optimal compilers and have no trouble understanding either.  Yet many learners opt for the mathematical `if (i % 2 == 0)`.

Comment: @chux: It is relevant though, because the optimization technique explained by Deduplicator is not going to work if you assume that `i % 2` produces the same results. In fact, you would likely never arrive at that kind of solution if you did not know to approach the problem by thinking in terms of the binary representation of integers. I actually would not have even bothered to reply to that comment if the assertion had not been made that an optimizing compiler will replace `i % 2` with `i & 1` - *that is invalid* - it might replace the entire expression `i % 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The `%` operator gives you the remainder of division.

An even number divided by **2** will always have a remainder of **0** regardless of sign. Odd numbers, if positive will have a remainder of **1** and if negative will have a remainder of **-1**. You only need to test a single case to determine if it is even however, and that is what you see happening in your existing code.

#### It is more efficient to test the least significant bit to determine if a number is odd though:

```
if (i & 1)    // Example: 0101 (5) & 0001 (1) == 1
  // Odd

else          // Example: 0100 (4) & 0001 (1) == 0
  // Even
```

That approach does not involve division and only has two possible outcomes instead of three when dealing with signed integers.